# How to export an Android module as a full project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-module

I have an Android project with many modules inside ( as small projects ) , i want to export or externilize one module as an independant project.

is there a simple way to do it or should i recreate a new project ?

Comment: you mean a library?

Comment: no it's not really a library , it's kind of a mini project.

Comment: You can create a jar file for each project and use that in the super folder

Comment: Well then. I would clone my project and refactor with a new name and then delete unrequited modules. This will save time as you wouldn't have to reinstall all the dependencies and add them to gradle.

Comment: I think you should edit your question as an android module is a full project (: